# How to make jsPlumb draggable element work on a touch device?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, touch, draggable, jsplumb

I have a very simple example of a single element that is marked draggable in jsPlumb. On a desktop browser it is draggable, but it is not working on a mobile/touch device. What do I need to do to enable dragging on touch devices with jsPlumb?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/lib/jsplumb.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
<style>
    .item {
        min-height: 40px;
        min-width: 80px;
        border: 1px solid green;
        position: absolute;
    }
</style>

<div id="item1" class="item">
    One
</div>
<script>
    jsPlumb.draggable("item1", );
    jsPlumb.ready(function() {});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried Touch Punch?